# Get connected Port

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, port

I want to build a program that will run on my Raspberry Pi and starts processes when I connect to it. I want to run a specific processes if there is a connection on a specific port.

So I need to get the port somebody is trying to connect to.

For example:
If I open `localhost:4444` in my browser I want to get 4444 as a string or an int.

It doesn’t need to be C#. Would be great, but it can also be in other languages.

Is this possible and how can I achieve that?

Comment: You'll need to decide ahead of time which ports you want to listen on -- you can't just listen on everything. Then you can use a `HttpListener` to listen on those ports. When you get a connection, check `context.Request.LocalEndPoint`

Comment: Does it need to be in C#? If so, I'm not much help, but if you're familiar with Node.js, I  may be able to help you out.

Comment: Are you trying to trigger a process when someone attempts to connect to _any_ port?

Comment: It doesn’t need to be C#, but with C# I Code most of my stuff.

Comment: No, I want to trigger a specific progress if somebody connects to a specific port. For example if somebody connects to port 4444 it should run start a apache server.

Comment: Surely you would just run Apache and configure it to be listen on port 4444.

Comment: If you're trying to start apache only when someone connects to port 4444 in order to save memory/CPU, you probably want to transfer the open connection to apache. That's not easy. You can do it with e.g. [Systemd Socket Activation](https://serverfault.com/questions/1033563/systemd-socket-activation-for-multiple-ports-on-apache)

Comment: System Socket Activation means, that if the apache server is started it automatically redirects to the apache server. Am I right?

Comment: When you say connect to the pi  how are you doing that?

Comment: Via the browser.

Comment: @CheckerPhil Systemd (note the 'd') socket activation means that systemd listens on the port for you. When someone connects to the port it starts a particular service (e.g. apache), and once the service has started it hands over the open socket. Note that the service needs to specifically support this -- being handed an open socket isn't a normal operation

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the explanation. I will look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listening for an incoming packet on *any port number*, rather than on a specific port number, is an unnatural act on Linux (the rPi's OS) and on most operating systems.

You could probably, with a lot of work, figure out how to do it with the [tcpdump command line utility](https://www.tcpdump.org/) and/or its underlying [libpcap](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap.3pcap.html) runtime library.  This subsystem intercepts network messages at the driver level and reports them.  You could write a hunk of code that notices an incoming connection request and launches a server (written in your language of choice) to listen on that port.

But, the server would not be launched in time to handle the request detected by tcpdump or libpcap. Instead, the OS on the rPi would reject it immediately with the [ECONNREFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/econnrefused/info) OS error. You would have to rely on the client software retrying the connection after the rPi had a chance to launch the server. But client software like web browsers don't automatically retry those refused connections.

You might be able to make this work, but it will always be a brittle solution and a miserable hack. You will be better off rethinking this system design. You should run servers (listeners) on any ports you think your clients will use.

I must mention the security hazards of the approach you propose. A cybercreep could crash your machine simply by running [nmap](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap) on it if you started servers upon receiving messages on random ports.

Comment: So it would be better if I write a program that looks for a specific port and than run something if somebody connects to this port?

Comment: Yes. You can even write a dotnet core program to listen on multiple ports; you'll need to listen separately on each one. Still, the design you propose is not consistent with the way most software uses TCP/IP networking.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.